# URL Redirect not working in iOS only

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iOS app (and desktop/mobile web/android application versions as well) that has the "Share to Facebook" functionality.  When users share to Facebook, the app generates a public link to the page and posts to Facebook.  When users click on the link from Facebook, it routes to a vanity URL and displays the page.

Unfortunately this routing functionality does not seem to be working on iOS devices. When clicking on the share link in the iOS Facebook app or copy/pasting the link into Safari on iOS, the original (non-vanity) link hangs with a blank page and no redirect happens.

I've tested this on Android, Windows desktop, Mac Desktop on multiple browsers with no issues.  The issue only persists on iOS in the Facebook in-app browser, in Safari, and also in Chrome for iOS.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: u found any solution @TG_P?

Comment: @Sushivam no I didn't. Still not sure where the issue came from but we ended up deprecating that functionality.